# StorageException: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

when I upload data on firebase it will show me this error.

When i have run this application in my android phone, i face this error on run time:

> StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
> Object does not exist at location.
> Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

they also print toast:

> uploading error Object does not exist at location.

```
addItemBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        selectedId = cuisineGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        selectedCuisineRadioBtn = findViewById(selectedId);

        foodCuisineCode = getFoodCuisineCode(selectedCuisineRadioBtn.getText().toString());

        Log.d(TAG, foodName.getText().toString().trim() + " : " + foodPrice.getText().toString().trim() + " : " + foodDesc.getText().toString().trim() +
            " : " + foodCuisineCode + " : " + foodCode);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(foodName.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(foodPrice.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(foodDesc.getText().toString()) || mainImageURI == null) {
            Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, "Please fill all details.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            bar.show();
        } else {
            foodNameSelected = foodName.getText().toString().trim();
            foodDescriptionSelected = foodDesc.getText().toString().trim();
            foodPriceSelected = foodPrice.getText().toString().trim();

            final StorageReference image_path = storageReference.child("food_images").child(foodName.getText().toString().trim() + ".jpg");

            //TODO add progress dialog

            progressDialog.setTitle("Saving Details");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we add your food to database");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

            if (isChanged) {
                image_path.putFile(mainImageURI).continueWithTask(new Continuation < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task < Uri >> () {
                    @Override
                    public Task < Uri > then(@NonNull Task < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            throw task.getException();
                        }

                        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                        return image_path.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Uri > () {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Uri > task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                            compressBitmap(downloadUri, foodName.getText().toString().trim());
                        } else {
                            String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "UPLOAD Error : " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```